# What is wrong with the following C++ class?

Tags: c++, floating-point, g++

So, basically I created a `Float` class to track down the range of floating point values used in the program. I just replace `float` in my program with `Float`. However, the output of my program changes when I use this class, but I can't figure out where is the problem.

```
#define real float

class Float
{
private:
real data;
static real minVal;
static real maxVal;

static void updateMinMax( real x )
{
    if ( x < minVal )
        minVal = x;

    if ( x > maxVal )
        maxVal = x;
}

public:
static real getMin() 
{
    return minVal;
}

static real getMax() 
{
    return maxVal;
}

Float()
{
    data = 0;
}

Float(real x) 
{
    data = x;
    updateMinMax(data);
}

void setFloat( real x )
{
    data = x;
    updateMinMax(data);
}

void setMaxOf( real x, real y )
{
    data = (x > y)? x : y;
    updateMinMax(data);
}

void setInt( int x )
{
    data = x;
    updateMinMax(data);
}

real getFloat() const
{
    return data;
}

operator int() const { return (int)data; }

void operator=(Float x)
{
    data = x.data;
    updateMinMax( data );
}

Float operator+(const Float& x) const
{
    updateMinMax( data + x.data );
    return Float(data + x.data);
}

void operator+=(Float x)
{
    data += x.data;
    updateMinMax( data );
}

Float operator-(const Float& x) const
{
    updateMinMax( data - x.data );
    return Float(data - x.data);
}

Float operator-() const
{
    updateMinMax( -data );
    return Float(-data);
}

void operator-=(Float x) 
{
    data -= x.data;
    updateMinMax( data );
}

Float operator*(const Float& x) const
{
    updateMinMax( data * x.data );
    return Float(data * x.data);
}

void operator*=(Float x) 
{
    data *= x.data;
    updateMinMax( data );
}

Float operator/(const Float& x) const
{
    updateMinMax( data / x.data );
    return Float(data / x.data);
}

void operator/=(Float x)
{
    data /= x.data;
    updateMinMax( data );
}

bool operator<(const Float& x) const
{
    return data < x.data;
}

bool operator<=(const Float& x) const
{
    return data <= x.data;
}

bool operator>(const Float& x) const
{
    return data > x.data;
}

bool operator>=(const Float& x) const
{
    return data >= x.data;
}

bool operator==(const Float& x) const
{
    return data == x.data;
}

friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& o, Float& x)
{
        o << x.data;
        return o;
}

friend istream& operator>>(istream& i, Float& x)
{
        i >> x.data;
        return i;
} 
};
```

Comment: And *how* does your output change? What is the expected output? What is the actual output? What is `real`? Do you have any warnings when compiling? Can you please make a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us?

Comment: No everything compiles fine. Its an Image Processing application that detect some part in the image. It detects it wrong when I use this class.

Comment: Show your program. If it's big then make a minimal example.

Comment: A sample of the actual and desired output, as well as a sample of the code usage would help. By the way, the integer conversion operator will truncate the decimal part of the float value, not a rounding of the value to the nearest integer. Is this the desired behavior?

Comment: Are you compiling with aggressive floating-point optimizations? Because this class probably wont trigger them. Is there a feedback-loop in your program? Because if there is, minute changes in input may cause large changes in output

Comment: Do not compare floats as `data == x.data`. And yes, give a **minimal** code, that is wrong

Comment: @Mr_Hic-up Yes, the intended thing is to mimick the integer typecasting that normally happens with floating point.

Comment: It would be advantages to create a set of unit tests for this class. The same unit tests can then be used on a normal `float` and the results can be compared to track down the problem. OR just debug it ;)

Comment: Could it be that the (int) cast is used by the compiler when some library function is called that has overloads with int and float arguments, causing unintentional data loss? Maybe make the int cast explicit.

Comment: and cast to float should probably be added

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following test program demonstrates at least one difference between using a float and your Float class:

```
void test(float x)
{
    cout<<"Called with float argument"<<endl;
}
void test(int x)
{
    cout<<"Called with int argument"<<endl;
}

int main() {
    Float arg1;
    float arg2;
    test(arg1);
    test(arg2);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Called with int argument
Called with float argument
```